# Цифровое дерево поиска. Основные операции

Tags: алгоритм, поиск, дерево, теория

Beчep добpый!

Сижу на даче и никак не могу найти информацию по цифровым деревьям поиска (**именно в этой последовательности**)

Единственное упоминание о них - Кнут [11] - что бы это не значило...

Сижу с телефона, поэтому PDF и DJVU открыть - проблема

Если скинете скринами или текстом - буду очень признателен!

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/428/%D0%91%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BD%D0%B0-c-c

Comment: цифровое - digital - двоичная?

Comment: @Cus
Нет - двиочное - это Binary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Итак, после 3х часов мытарства по библиотеке и п̶о̶л̶т̶о̶р̶а̶ ̶л̶и̶т̶р̶а̶ ̶в̶о̶д̶к̶и̶ долгого опрашивания препода нашел описание алгоритма

> Цифровое дерево поиска - это такое дерево поиска, в котором набор
>   битовых чисел кодируется в виде некоего кода (часто двоичного или
>   шестнадцатиричного)

Пример:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]